# Fedora 18 in Oracle VirtualBox on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, virtualbox, virtualization, fedora

I want to install [Fedora 18](http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora) [Desktop] in Oracle VirtualBox 4.2.10 r84104. [My system is Windows Vista 32 bit]

I have followed the following steps while configuring the Virtual Machine.

- Memory Size 800MB (suggested size is 768 MB)
- Virtual HardDrive (Type - VirtualBox Disk Image)
- Storage on Physical HardDrive as Dynamic
- Virtual Hard Drive Size `8 GB`

When I start the VirtualBox it shows the option to start Fedora. The loading initiates then the following screen appears

[image]

This is followed by a blank [black] screen for a several minutes and this screen shows up,

[image]

Seems to me the OS does load, but there is some issue. Which I can't figure out. Please help.

*Note:* The .iso is not corrupted because I can use it install it as Dual OS

---

**UPDATE:**

---

I tried the same with Fedora 15

Settings.

- Memory Size 1024MB (suggested size is 768 MB)
- Virtual HardDrive (Type - VirtualBox Disk Image)
- Storage on Physical HardDrive as Dynamic
- Virtual Hard Drive Size `32 GB`

and it worked! But when it started it showed "GNOME could not be loaded" and the same "(Oh no something has gone wrong screen)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIs61.jpg)" I logged out and logged in again, and GNOME started and everything turned out to be fine.

Then I tried with Fedora18 again and to my surprise it loaded properly too. Initially it too showed GNOME could not be loaded, but relogging in did the trick again.

So finally problem solved (*Don't know how!*) I am yet to figure out why I ran into issues with Fedora18 initially and why did they miraculaously disappear when I worked with Fedora15 and then came back to Fedora18.

Anyone who has and idea on this behavior, please do respond and help to track the issue that occurred in the first place.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but neither of those last two errors are the show-stopper here. There's something else wrong, as both of those errors are recoverable based on my readings.

Comment: Did you try another OS? fedora 18 has many problems.

Comment: Did you try another OS? Vista has many problems.

Comment: @Sepahrad Nopes. Haven't tried any other Linux yet

Comment: @ta.speot.is Not yet. Will try and check

Comment: @JohninOhio Guess i will search about it a bit more. Couldn't find anything in VM context. If I find anything will post it here

Comment: Try another Linux Distributions. and Feed back here

Comment: Failed to access prfctr msr is definetely a kernel error.

Comment: @SepahradSalour Updated my question, have a look

Comment: I read it, Please read this post of me http://superuser.com/questions/586701/special-instructions-for-centos-vbox-virtual-machine/586710#586710 and create another VirtualOS and feedback here.