# Special instructions for CentOS VBox virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, iso-image

I am gearing up to create a [CentOS 5.5 server](http://vault.centos.org/5.5/isos/x86_64/CentOS-5.5-x86_64-LiveCD.iso) virtual machine in VBox and was wondering if there are special instructions, configurations or settings that I should be aware of ahead of time.

Specifically:

1. What type of Linux should I select?
2. Does it require special device drivers?
3. Recommended memory, disk, etc. settings?
4. Is there a VBox guide specific for this version of CentOS (I couldn't find one)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the VBox
2. Click on **New**
3. in Name field Enter your ideal name For example **MyOS**
4. Type: Linux
5. Version: RedHat
6. Click on next and Enter your memory size it's 512MB by default
7. Click on next and choose **Create virtual hard drive now**
8. Click on create
9. In hard drive file type choose **VDI (VirtualBox Disk Image)**
10. Click on next
11. In store on physical hard drive choose **Dynamically Alocated**
12. Click next, Enter your virtual hard drive size it's 8GB by default.
13. Click create
14. Now start your machine
15. Then choose your **Disk Image** and click **Start**